# Restricting a Change to Only 1 List

Tags: python

I have nested lists (ie. `[[list1],[list2]]` and I want to make a change to only the first list.
My function is given as below:

```
function_name(data, list_number, change)
```

*should return a change to only the list_number provided in the data*

So my overall question is, how do I restrict this change to only the list_number given? If this is unclear please feel free to ask and clarify.

Ex:
*Where the 'change' is already known which index it is going to replace, in this case it's going to replace the 2nd index of the first list (ie. 2)*

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]  
function_name(data, 1, 6) 
data = [[1,6,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I have no idea where to even begin as the index is 'unknown' (ie. given by the user when the function is called)

Comment: can you share what you try,  your sample data and what will be sample output

Answer (score 0):

List items are referenced via their index and nested lists can work the same way.

If your list were:

```
list = [['nest1_1', 'nest1_2']['nest2_1', 'nest2_2']]
```

You could change it in the following ways:

```
list[0] = ['nesta_1', 'nesta_2']
list[1][0] = 'second_1'
```

This would make your list now be:

```
[['nesta_1', 'nesta_2']['second_1', 'nest2_2']]
```

Comment: but what if the index that I want to replace is 'unknown' (ie. the user enters it when the function is called)

Comment: Then you would need to have that be a variable in your function.

Comment: could you suggest a way to do this?

Comment: In a function you can call the information that is brought in with the name you called in when you defined your function.  For your example you called it `function_name(data, list_number, change)` so you would then reference the outside list as `data` and the inner index as `list_number` and the new value as `change` which would look like `data[list_number] = change` though you probably need another value to indicate both which list in your list of lists and which item in that list so it would really be `data[list_number][item_number] = change`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

def element_change(data, index_list, element_to_change, change):
    a =''.join([ str(i) for i in data[index_list]])
    data[index_list][a.find(str(element_to_change))] = change
    return data

print(element_change(data, 0, 2, 6))
```

**Input:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 6, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Simply what it does is *casting list to string* and *merging* them in order to be able to use `find()` method to find the **index**.